# How do I remove duplicates when using the random sort?

Tags: 7, views

I have created a view where I am displaying the the node title and a logo (a cck field). In the arguments I have passed the taxonomy term name.

In the result a node is displaying 2 or 3 times; I already checked the distinct checkbox in the Query settings but that also does not work. I have used the random sort, which seems to cause the duplicates; when I remove the random sort, it works fine.

How can I avoid the duplicates without disabling the random sort?

Comment: it would be actually nice if someone explains the reason(s) for the duplicates and the counter-measures. having 5 solutions that 'maybe' work is only semi-optimal

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can apply GROUP BY or DISTINCT by enabling views aggregation settings to remove duplicate records.
1. Go and edit your view
2. In **Advanced » OTHER** section by enabling **Use aggregation: Yes**
3. In **FIELDS** or **FILTER CRITERIA** section, select and apply **Aggregation settings** for which fields you want to group by or distinct.

Comment: I have the sample problem, I enable use aggregation and in my filed there is not `distinct` select, which type I should select in Aggregation type?

Answer (score 39):

The simple way to achieve distinct values in a view is to make the following:

1. Go and edit your view
2. In Advanced » OTHER section click on "Query setting"
3. Check "Distinct" check-box.

Comment: In my question I have already  mentioned that I have checked the Distinct option in the Query settings.

Comment: Eugene and Clive, It is work, Thanks a lot for sharing this.

Answer (score 8):

The simple way to achieve distinct values using Views is to do the following:

1. Go and edit your view
2. In Advanced » OTHER section click on "Query setting"
3. Check "Distinct" check-box.

You can apply GROUP BY or DISTINCT by enabling views aggregation settings to remove duplicate records.

1. Go and edit your view
2. In Advanced » OTHER section by enabling Use aggregation: Yes
3. In FIELDS or FILTER CRITERIA section, select and apply Aggregation settings for which fields you want to group by or distinct.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question has already been answered, but for some of use these solutions don't work. However, after doing some research I found a solution that does work for my needs.

I found a really useful workaround that allowed me to fix this. I have posted the code snippet to DropBucket. Basically you implement a Drupal 7 query alter hook that checks all views queries for query comments that specify a groupby clause and field. Then it adds that groupby to the SQL query.

```
/**
 *  Found this trick on theoleschool.com.
 *  
 *  Description: Allows the view developer to specify the query
 *  group by action in the query comments. Great way to force the
 *  removal of duplicates.
 *  
 *  Just go into your query comments and type in "groupby:" with
 *  that colon followed by the field you want to group by.
 * 
 *  Examples...
 *  groupby:node.nid
 *  groupby:file_managed_file_usage.fid
 * 
 *  Ref-Comment: http://theoleschool.com/comment/496#comment-496
 *  Ref-Article: http://theoleschool.com/blog/using-hookviewsalter-add-group-statement
 */
function mymodule_query_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  if ($query->hasTag('views')) {
    static $count;
    $view =& $query->getMetaData('view');

    if (strstr($groupby = $view->query->options['query_comment'], 'groupby')) {
      list($action, $field) = explode(':', $groupby);

      if (strlen($field) > 0) {
        $query->groupBy($field);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

http://dropbucket.org/node/153

The source reference is in the comments on the page.

Comment: I want to add that there are known issues with DISTINCT not functioning properly in Views 3.3 and higher.

Comment: Instead of doing the above you can just check the view's name and then add the group by.

Comment: It works great. None of the solution here worked for me except this...coding always rock to find final solution :)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Ultimately I solved it by installing the [**Views Distinct**](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_distinct) module.

> Relationships or other joins in Views often create "duplicate" results. For example, a node with a field that has multiple values may show up in the View once per value in the multi-value field. It's frustrating, and the "DISTINCT" SQL query option in the Views UI does not actually solve the problem because the result row is technically distinct. **Views Distinct** aims to give a simple GUI method to remove or aggregate these "duplicate" rows.

Answer (score 0):

None of these other methods worked for me, but [Views Random Seed](https://drupal.org/project/views_random_seed) module actually did the trick. Though, my issues were more related to using a pager. Here is a quote from that module's project page:

> Adds a random order handler with seed. If a constant integer argument N is specified in the sql RAND() function, it is used as the seed value, which produces a repeatable sequence of column values. This makes it possible to have paging and not having items show up twice.
>   It's also possible to compute a custom seed using PHP, allowing you to create pseudo randoms numbers based on variables such as the date of the day.

Answer (score 0):

Not to wake up an old thread, but the answer (if using Drupal 7 and an exposed search filter) is to check "remove search score" under "search:search terms".

Under "Filter Criteria"

Add "Search:Search Terms"

Check "Remove Search Score"

Click "Apply (all displays)"

Click Save

Answer (score 0):

Had problems with multi value date fields. The items were displayed as often as a date was entered. None of the other here mentioned solutions worked for me. But then I found a D6 solution that still works in D7 [there](http://www.capellic.com/blog/cure-duplicate-nodes-in-a-view).

`hook_views_pre_render(&$view)` is the magic word. In the example it's limited down to one certain display of one certain view only. Hope it helps.

```
function MYMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  $used_nids = array();

  if ($view->name == 'events') {

    if ($view->current_display == 'page_2') {

      foreach ($view->result as $row) {

        if (!in_array($row->nid, $used_nids)) {

          $new_view_result[] = $row;
          $used_nids[] = $row->nid;
        }
      }
      $view->result = $new_view_result;
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** Unfortunately this one subtracts the number of duplicate items from the view if a limit was set. If someone maybe finds a solution for this, please comment!

Answer (score 0):

I have multiple `Date fields` and want to sort by the start of the `FIRST date`...
Here is how it did work:
In `Views->advanced->Other: use aggregation: YES`
And then:
`SORT CRITERIA->Aggregation settings->Aggregation type: COUNT`

I expected `count` to give me the number instead of the instance, but it made the result distinct...