# How to make URL arguments available as tokens in Rewrite Results of a Field in a View?

Tags: 7, uri, views

Is it possible to make URL arguments, e.g.

```
http://mysite.com/arg1/arg2/arg3
```

available as tokens in the rewrite results settings for a field in views e.g. for the above these would be available for use (among other existing tokens) as:

```
[arg1] [arg2] [arg3]
```

**Background**

I am developing Views using OpenLayers maps with filtered items place in an overlay on them. When the user interacts with the map to remove items, I want to retain the position of the map (an not have it revert to a default zoom and position) when the page reloads. By being able to access the URL arguments i.e. longitude and latitude, I can then rewrite the filter URL so that these are sent back to the page.

But I'm sure there are other scenarios that don't use maps that people would find answers to the question useful for.

Answer (score 6):

If you do not want to actually use a contextual filter, you can use a "Global: Null" contextual filter, use the Contextual filters options to assign the value from the argument position you are interested in and then that becomes available as a %1/!1 replacement token without actually affecting the query.

Answer (score 4):

If `arg2` and `arg3` are, or can be, arguments/contextual filters in the View in question, you should be able to use `!1` and `!2` in the rewrite.

I am ignoring `arg1` as that really can't easily be dynamic.

ADDITION:

This could be another case of my assuming D7 hasn't gotten rid of D6 features, but a quick screen grab here (I don't have a D7 testbed handy right at this sec, sorry) shows this as part of rewrite when arguments are present:

[image]

This is a quick View with two arguments, a node nid and type, and when I rewrite this field (the title), I can put in `Hello [title] where nid is !1 and type is !2` and it works.

2ND ADDITION:

Even though this answer no longer is valid to the issue at hand (see abounding comments on both answers), @Molot did confirm that these replacement patterns are available in D7:

[image]

so perhaps this and his answer will help someone else looking out there.

Comment: Jimajamma so would I, for example, put !2 or [!2] directly in the text box for 'rewrite this field' - as in: http://i44.tinypic.com/4rrgy0.png - this doesn't seem to work, as this screen shot shows - !2 or [!2] is output. By the way I am (necessarily) using aggregation so don't know whether this is interfering - see screenshot: http://i44.tinypic.com/2vmc84m.png Reason for aggregation here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/79064/1082 (thanks for your input so far Jimajamma)

Comment: I've never seen the !2 or !3 notation before as tokens in the rewrite results for a view, I have to admit though I hope it works with some advice on where I am going wrong with using it as per last comment.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/e5X2y.png - screenshot from D7 - works. NID is forst contextual filter there

Comment: Thanks Mołot (+1) and Jimajamma - this has now started to appear and I'll experiment further to confirm - I think something is a bit 'flakey' with my setup as these did not show before. If all's well I would like to accept Jimajamma's answer (thanks Mołot - I'll upvote all your posts, when I come back to confirm...)

Comment: Hope to still accept this answer, once again thank you Jimajamma for your answer, Mołot for supporting it and also input from Clive. Update: although I can see the `!1` etc. in the available rewrite tokens, I get this output literally in the URL `%211` for `!1` or `%212` for `!2` I think I'll come back to it later for another look, with a fresh pair of eyes.

Comment: I've also just realised that my particular situation does not apply - I wanted the long lat part of the URL for openlayer maps to be passed back in - 2 issues: 1) the long lat part of the URL is preceded by a # (which is never passed to the server-side (upon which Drupal runs), remains on the browser but Javascript can see it) and 2) this long lat part doesn't 'belong' to any particular content queried by the view so another approach is needed (try to alter the way the URL for an openlayer map is constructed so that this is visible to the server). Nonetheless your answers are much appeciated.

Comment: Ah.  Well let us all know if we can take another whack at it.  If it is something like `www.yourhost.com/some/path#latlong` the `#latlong` is in fact being sent to the backend, that's an anchor tag, it will just be basically ignored if it doesn't exist on the server (but it certainly can be seen by drupal).  Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming arguments you want to use are not views arguments or contextual filters, if you wantthem as tokens, you basically need to create a module that implements [hook_tokens()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_tokens/7) and [hook_token_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_token_info/7), as [described in the API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!token.inc/7). I don't think anyone did it already.

Here is how I'd do it:

```
function yourmodule_token_info() {
  $type = array(
    'name' => t('GET'),
    'description' => t('Tokens related to $_GET superglobal.'),
  );
  $tokens = array();
  foreach($_GET as $key => $val) { //discard $val now
    $tokens[$key] = array(
      'name' => $key,
      'description' => "\$_GET['$key']",
    );
  }
  return array(
    'types' => array('get' => $type),
    'tokens' => array('get' => $tokens),
  );
}

function yourmodule_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data = array(), array $options = array()) {
  if($type == 'get') {
    $replacements = array();
    foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
        $replacements[$original] = (string)$_GET[$name];
    }
    return $replacements;
  }
}
```

Of course code above is **not production ready**, it ignores proper type handling, security issues and so on. It's meant to set you on the right track, but you need to apply your own sanity before deploying it. I take no responsibility for abuse. Read about the reasons it was removed in the first place before you decide to add it back, and be careful to restore only what you really need.

If you want parameters accesible by [`arg()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) instead of $_GET, of course in hook_tokens iterate over them with `while`:

```
function yourmodule_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data = array(), array $options = array()) {
  if($type == 'arg') {
    $replacements = array();
    $i = 0;
    while ( NULL !== ($arg = arg($i))) {
        $replacements["arg:$i"] = (string)$arg;
    }
    return $replacements;
  }
}
```

Change `yourmodule_token_info()` accordingly.

Comment: +1 thank you very much @Mołot So, had this feature been considered for views by the developers involved, in the past and decided against? It is likely I will accept your answer, I'll give the code you gave a try.

Comment: @therobyouknow tokens from $_GET are costly and messes with cache, afaik. And see my updated answer before you'll try.

Comment: if arg2 and arg3 are actually arguments or contextual filters for the View in question, you should be able to just use `!2,` `!3` in the rewrite (I am ignoring arg1 as that really can't easily be dynamic)

Comment: @Jimajamma my mistake - I assumed it's not about that. Blindness to the obvious. If you'll post it as an answer I'll gladly upvote.

Comment: Thanks also for your input Jimajamma - but I'm not sure if I have used your `!2` etc. suggestion correctly - the string `!2` gets output directly from my View - see my comments (and screenshots below your answer)

Comment: Just nit-picking, but you should really `switch ($name)` inside the `foreach` loop in `hook_tokens()`; as it is, even if you define several token types in the `_info()` hook, they'll all be subject to exactly the same replacement logic

Comment: Clive thanks for your input I will bear that in mind. By the way, are you familar with using `!2` and `!3` notation in rewrite results to obtain URL arguments for the output of a field in a View? I've never seen this before and tried Jimajamma's suggestion above but I just get `!2 `output itself as a string!

Comment: @Clive I meant it as an outline, hence *"It's meant to set you on the right track, but you need to apply your own sanity before deploying it."* - but feel free to edit my code and add that check too. I admit at the moment I don't have time to rewrite it :( Will try to remember and do it tomorrow, if you will not.

Comment: @therobyouknow Sorry no, I've only ever used/seen `%1` etc for Views placeholders. Bearing in mind the various formats [`format_string()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/format_string/7) provides, though, it kind of makes sense. Though (hypothetically) the `!` would pass the string through unsanitized which might not be desirable

Comment: @Mołot You're right you've disclaimed that pretty well - I just breezed through the code :)

Comment: Clive, to be exact, `!` as in exclamation mark character followed directly by the numeral 2 i.e. `!2` not percentage character followed by numeral 2 i.e. `%2`. I'm really scratching my head on this one, what did Jimajamma mean (please come back and advise) also Mołot concurs with using `!2` etc. Mołot do you know what Jimajamma meant by using `!2` ?!

Comment: @therobyouknow Did you read the `format_string()` docs I linked to?

Comment: @Clive yes, that `format_string()` is worth knowing - it's like a kind of `printf()` in the `C` language but I think it is rather that Jimajamma's answer is assuming that such notations `!1` and `!2` in rewrite results in views in D6 have been carried forward into D7, as he explains in his [edited answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/79147/1082). As `format_string()` shows, `!2` is inserting the value of the variable `2` as is but that variable has to be defined in the first place, i.e. for my case, this variable `2` would be the arg2 of the URL.

Comment: Yep might well be that, I didn't really use Views in Drupal 6 so I can't help there I'm afraid

Comment: Clive yes seems like this is the case, sadly. So Mołot's answer would likely be the accepted one once I try it out and if successful. Though apparently this may have been considered in the past and discounted on the grounds of security - Mołot welcome your further thoughts on this when you can. Thanks everyone so far. Most appreciated.

Comment: @therobyouknow http://i.stack.imgur.com/e5X2y.png D7 supports this too, just tested it. Dunno why it does not work for you. Jimajamma's answer is OK if arguments are in contextual filters. At least works for me. (LOL 'm fighting against my answer being accepted)

Comment: Thanks Mołot (+1) and Jimajamma - this has now started to appear and I'll experiment further to confirm - I think something is a bit 'flakey' with my setup as these did not show before. If all's well I would like to accept Jimajamma's answer (thanks Mołot - I'll upvote all your posts...)

Comment: @therobyouknow DO NOT SERIAL UPVOTE ME! And honestly, upvotes on this post earned me 2x more rep than acceptance would, so no need to worry ;) After all I asked Jimajamma to post his comment as an answer, right? And I was fighting to prove his way is easier :P So it should be obvious I don't mind his post to be accepted.