# Field:REWRITE , Contextual filters Views 3

Tags: views

i am pretty new to drupal 7 , and i have managed to create a view (conferences_details) with a contextual filter Content:Nid, the link to the view is now conference_details/%
How then do i include node id to the title field in the page that links to the respective
conference_details/% view page.?
I have tried to REWRITE output field:Title as link using:
conference_details/%nid
conference_details/%Nid
conference_details/[%nid]
conference_details/[Nid]
conference_details/[nid]
with no luck. Can you please help. on how to do this . what i m trying to do

Comment: Also see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79139/how-to-make-url-arguments-available-as-tokens-in-rewrite-results-of-a-field-in-a for another potential option

Answer (score 1):

You should call **Content: Nid (Nid)** field above the conference_details field,
as showing below
[image]
Than only [nid] will be available for **REPLACEMENT PATTERNS** for `Rewrite the output of this field` as `Output this field as a link`

edit the **Content: Nid (Nid)** configuration
[image]

Comment: Dankie that did solve may problem, but i have noticed that displaying the "Nid:" on the pages isn't that cool, i will try to output the Title as the link now. do you think appending [node:title] to the output as link will work?

Comment: make that "Exclude from display" from NID field configuration see my edit answer screen shot