# how to stop repeated content in view

Tags: views, commerce

I am showing content from product content type of commerce module using view but view is showing some repeated content.how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check [How do I remove duplicates when using the random sort?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38450/drupal-7-views-how-to-remove-duplicates-causing-from-random-sort) before?

If it does not help you check [views_distinct](https://drupal.org/project/views_distinct) module

> Relationships or other joins in Views often create "duplicate"
>   results. For example, a node with a field that has multiple values may
>   show up in the View once per value in the multi-value field. It's
>   frustrating, and the "DISTINCT" SQL query option in the Views UI does
>   not actually solve the problem because the result row is technically
>   distinct. This module aims to give a simple GUI method to remove or
>   aggregate these "duplicate" rows.