# how to limit view to just show each type one time?

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I have a content type what is **news**, the news has a field type that is **List (text)** *to keep different types of news*. for example I have Health, Sport, Economic and etc.

So now I am going to create a block and have each of these type in that as a hyperlink.

I can do it and I created a new view block but each **news_type** may showing more than one time according to published content.

How to set the view (for block) to just show **news_types** and show them just one time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by following the steps given below:

1. Enable aggregation under Advanced Accordion of the view
2. Add Nid field & set aggregation type as Count Distinct
3. Exclude Nid field from display
4. Add news type field & set Aggregation type as Group results together, in Group Column select Value option from dropdown
5. Remove Publishing Date from sort criteria

Please check attached screenshot for reference

[image]

and for more information you can check this [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38450/drupal-7-views-how-to-remove-duplicates-causing-from-random-sort?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 3):

You can set Distinct in the advanced settings of your view. A distinct will only show unique records. So if you have a list of all Lists then it will show all unique values of List

Comment: Thanks man, But the other answer by @VishalPatil was better. Thanks anyway :)