# How to merge these results?

Tags: views

I wonder why these results don't merge. This is the result of searching by postcode.
As you can see it returns 2 times the same shop with another deal. I need it to return the shop once with both deals on it. Thanks in advance! Pictures below:

[image: detail]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Found two modules that might help with your issue:

[Views Merge Rows](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_merge_rows) - provides a way to combine rows with the same content in the specified fields.

OR

[Views Fields Combine](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_fields_combine) - Similar to the one above, but hasn't been updated since 2012.

Experiment and see which one works best. You may need to use Rewrite Option too.

Comment: Let me know which one works for you. May have a project that needs this feature too.

Comment: None works. Can't just merge the first two fields only it's all or nothing. I'm just grouping them atm

Comment: Did you make sure that Distinct is chosen in the Query for Views? If that doesn't work, you can try this one [link](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_distinct) .

Comment: i have that installed already :/ still doesn't work. I tried the Distinct in Query settings but still displays duplicates

Comment: These timers make it impossible to aggregate. if I check the Distinct in Query Setting and set Aggregation on yes, it filters the duplicates but then they're completely removed. That's too much.

Answer (score 0):

> "You can apply GROUP BY or DISTINCT by enabling views aggregation
> settings to remove duplicate records.
>
> 1. Go and edit your view
> 2. In Advanced » OTHER section by enabling Use aggregation: Yes
> 3. In FIELDS or FILTER CRITERIA section, select and apply Aggregation settings for which fields you want to group by or distinct."

Taken from:
[How do I remove duplicates when using the random sort?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38450/drupal-7-views-how-to-remove-duplicates-causing-from-random-sort)

Comment: If I follow your instructions it results nothing. Aggregation: yes, Group results by ... 
also an instant SQL error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS field_data_field_logo_, location.name AS location_name, location.postal_code ' at line 1