# hide repeated data from my view table for some specific field

Tags: hooks, views

[image][image]

****how can hide repeated data from my view table. i want to print employee Id and name field only once for each group.
can you please help me out.****

---

I am fetching two table in view using JOIN.So few data gets repeated with respect to foreign key. So I need to hide those field value...
    Suggest me any solution...distinct and aggregation mixing up my data..

---

Comment: Can you show me the views configuration

Comment: you can check my view configuration...

Comment: I think this link may provide you the solution http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38450/how-do-i-remove-duplicates-when-using-the-random-sort

Comment: if i am apllying distinct view and filter as a duplicate then all the related record along with row went out.

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the month and aggregate the salary field as SUM,
if you only want to suppress display of 2+ column values try the [views merge rows](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_merge_rows) module

Comment: i want my output like printing  emp id, name only once and then whole buch of salray and month detail...

Answer (score 0):

Enable Aggregation in the advanced settings of your view and group the fields.

Comment: aggregation mixing all the things any other idea...using any function?