# How to fetch content data based on Node reference field into a view

Tags: 7, views, nodes

i am attempting to fetch the records based on node reference fields into a content type page.

i added node reference fields "news" & "Articles" (and many more) into my "Industry" Content type:

[image: image 1]

Now i've created a view with a filter (Content type= industries). Find the snap of the view here:

[image]

i want to list down all the selected/inserted news and articles (along with their content data) into the view. (currently its fetching only titles but with lot of repetition of the titles from both content types.)

Comment: try adding content: Body in fields @Esar -ul-haq Qasmi

Comment: Thanks, i was absolutely missing this thing, but the other problem persists that is repetition, that is if there are 5 news and 10 articles, so the news are repeating with 10 articles. How to control this ?

Comment: select the checkbox Distinct under query settings in OTHER below Advanced @Esar -ul-haq Qasmi

Comment: I've done this thing, also tried Group by and aggregate fields options. but no luck. see here http://prntscr.com/b8aqr3 , the red pointed news are repeating every time with articles in views perview

Comment: Can this link help u http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38450/how-do-i-remove-duplicates-when-using-the-random-sort  @Esar -ul-haq Qasmi

Comment: This link guides about aggregate and group by methods and i've tried both, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can either construct your news and article views as attachments and attach them to your view, or you can bring the content for news and articles in field by field in the main view.

Using attachments might help you to end up with less repetition without having to use query aggregation.